# USB Power Adapter gets really hot?

Tags: charging, charger

Is it okay if your power adapter gets hot, because mine gets really really hot, it's kinda burning to the touch and I'm really worried, especially because my Iphone is brand new and i don't live in US, but that is where i got it from, and there aren't any apple stores in my country so i can go and ask for help. If anyone knows any solution, i would be really grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Mmm I think it all depends on how much you use it and for how long you've been having it.

Though if you use it for several hours straight it may start getting a little bit hot (or even worse sometimes), it's common.

---

But if you think it's way out the normal, you may want to consider about purchasing a new one maybe?

You can either purchase the official one from the [Apple Online Store](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD810LL/A/apple-5w-usb-power-adapter?fnode=97).

Or on Amazon (thus today only 12/07/2016 is the [Prime Day](https://www.amazon.com/b?ie=UTF8&node=11448061011)!) [take a look](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_3_13?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=apple%20charger%20iphone%206&sprefix=Apple%20charger%2Caps%2C231)!